# 'TextField' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to ReactJs. I got this error when I'm trying on a tutorial. My form.js file is,

```
import React,{UseState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';


const initialFvalues ={
    id:0,
    fullName:'',}

export default function form(){

const [values,setValues] = UseState(initialFvalues);

return(
    <form>
        <Grid>
            <Grid container>
                <Grid item xs={6}><TextField variant="Outlined" label="Full Name" value={values.fullName}/></Grid>                    
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </form>
)
}
```

The error is:

`TextField' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef`

Can someone please help

Comment: You are missing the import for Textfield `import { Grid, Textfield  } from '@material-ui/core';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

missing import of textfield. Please add below import in your code.

```
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
or
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
```

Answer (score 3):

Missing import statement for [TextField](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#import)

Add the following to your imports

```
import { Grid, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
```

or

```
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
```

Comment: both are worked fine. but it still not appearing the text fields in the page. Just the empty page. I just did import those _TextField_ statement. Is there anything to do.?

Comment: I would suggest you to go through the [tutorial](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/) first

Comment: I'm already followed a tutorial and then this error found. But there is no any error in that tutorial video when it's developing. Anyway Thank you..

Answer (score 2):

You haven't import the TextField from other file

import it as

```js
import Texfield from './textfield.js';
```

or

```js
import Texfield from '@material-ui/core';
```

Comment: I tried on both of them, but also these errors appears respectively,  **in 1st import**  `Module not found: Can't resolve './textfield.js'`    **in 2nd import**      `Attempted import error: '@material-ui/core' does not contain a default export (imported as 'TextField')`   Is there any solution for this.?